# Can't get my regular expression to match

Tags: .net, regex

It seems to me this should match just fine.  Can someone point out to me what I'm doing wrong?

Regular Expression:

```
^.* ATM DEPOSIT (?'Month'\d{2})-(?'Day'\d{2}) #(?'Reference'[0-9A-Za-z]) .*$
```

String:

```
BKOFAMERICA ATM DEPOSIT 07-05 #006475 CUSTOMER 2323 BANK OF AMERICA, SAVANNAH, GA
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a `+`.

Your expression.

```
^.* ATM DEPOSIT (?'Month'\d{2})-(?'Day'\d{2}) #(?'Reference'[0-9A-Za-z]) .*$
```

Correct expression.

```
^.* ATM DEPOSIT (?'Month'\d{2})-(?'Day'\d{2}) #(?'Reference'[0-9A-Za-z]+) .*$
```

Apart from that, since you're not interested in anything before the date and after the reference, there is no need to match it. Use:

```
ATM DEPOSIT (?'Month'\d{2})-(?'Day'\d{2}) #(?'Reference'[0-9A-Za-z]+)
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the + at the end of the submatch. It should look like this

```
(?'Reference'[0-9A-Za-z]+)
```